# Changing Default magento 2.3 datepicker format

Tags: magento2, datepicker

The default Magento date-picker format for birth-date on create account page is `mm/dd/yyyy`. how can i change it into `dd/mm/yyyy` format in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Datepicker format is via customizations of the widget of the datepicker from jQuery UI. Check the DOB template and see how that's being triggered, if I am not wrong, they hardcode it via PHP block rendering. If I were you, I'll override the template and create a newer input field with the new call to the javascript widget so you can actually customize it.

Here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_calendar.html

For more information about the base of it: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

You have the parameters to set it. If you check here you will see the whole specs of the custom Magento widget: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/web/mage/calendar.js

PS. I personally bring a third-party datepicker library because I don't like the basics from jQuery UI. This is my favorite: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Do you the default magento block where the date format is set? i can overirde it

Comment: @Nafisa you should not override it. You should extend it if you need or call another library from a third-party repo and include it on your theme. Check how widgets are being developed on the Magento core UI. Follow the dev docs for good practice. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/jquery-widgets-about.html

Answer (score 0):

Magestore has provided the solution

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/set-date-format-in-magento-2-by-your-own/

Comment: No, this does not help